# HTML canvas.getContext performance

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm wondering how fast `canvas.getContext("2d")` is. Does it just return a property, or does it have to create something every time?

In my code, I pass around canvases, not contexts, and I get the context every time, like so:

```
function someFuncUsedPrettyOften(canvas) {
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 80, 100);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you have the solution ... pass around context, not canvas

Comment: The first time it is created it needs some setup however once created the context is permanent so all subsequent calls to `getContext` will  just returns the reference. With that said you are better off passing the context as you can access the canvas from the context `ctx.canvas` while `canvas.getContext` needs to validate the arguments making it quicker to use ctx, rather than canvas.

Comment: @HelderSepulveda but im getting the canvas onclick, so I can't really pass around the context

Comment: Share some more code ... hard to help with what you got ... assuming you have a list of canvas, just like you have that you can have a list of context